# Running rabbitmqadmin in docker fails

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, rabbitmqadmin

I cant get the rabbitmqadmin to work in my rabbitmq docker.

I have this Dockerfile:

```
FROM rabbitmq:3-management

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python

ADD rabbitmqadmin /usr/local/bin/rabbitmqadmin
ADD rabbitconf.json /rabbitconf.json

RUN chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/rabbitmqadmin

CMD ["/usr/local/bin/rabbitmqadmin -q import /rabbitconf.json"]
```

Build it like this:

```
docker build --tag=myrabbit .
```

Run it like this:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:15672 myrabbit
```

It does not work... The log shows:

```
/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 8: /usr/local/bin/rabbitmqadmin -q import     /rabbitconf.json: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong ?

BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've mixed up the shell and exec formats for the `CMD` instruction.

```
CMD /usr/local/bin/rabbitmqadmin -q import /rabbitconf.json
```

Should work.

For more information see http://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#cmd.

I'll leave the following for anyone else debugging similar problems:

The parent image `rabbitmq:3-management` is declares an `ENTRYPOINT` which runs the `docker-entrypoint.sh` script. Your `CMD` instruction is passed to this `ENTRYPOINT` script as an argument. Somewhere in the script, things go wrong.

Without seeing the script, we can't really debug the problem. However, one workaround would be to override the `ENTRYPOINT` instruction either in your Dockerfile or on the command line. For example, what happens if you run:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:15672 --entrypoint="" myrabbit
```

Note that this isn't the correct solution; you should try to use the `ENTRYPOINT` script of the parent image, or fix it so that it does what you want.

Comment: Hi Adrian thanks for your answer. I have tried your suggestion and I get the same error. The rabbitmq:3-management is the official image from rabbitmq and the entrypoint.sh is:

`#!/bin/bash
set -e

if [ "$1" = 'rabbitmq-server' ]; then
 chown -R rabbitmq /var/lib/rabbitmq
fi

exec "$@"
`

The Dockerfile is here (https://github.com/docker-library/rabbitmq/blob/46b8c75905e6666eb737c17a5d813cf41efbe4f7/Dockerfile)

I have also tried to change the CMD to this but the same error:

´CMD ["/rabbitmqadmin", "-q", "import", "/rabbitconf.json"]´

Am I thinking this wrong? Is this possible ?

Comment: Ok, just debug it from a shell: `docker run -it myrabbit /bin/bash` then try running `/usr/local/bin/rabbitmqadmin -q import /rabbitconf.json` and check you have the syntax correct and the files are accessible.

Comment: Ah, I think you've just got the CMD syntax wrong; try removing the square brackets

Comment: Hi that kinda worked... now I get:
*** Could not connect: [Errno 111] Connection refused
thats because the server is not started, in the rabbitmq:3-management Dockerfile there is a CMD and from the docker documentation there can only be one CMD, If you list more than one CMD then only the last CMD will take effect.

Comment: Yup, that's a completely different problem. You now need to use something like supervisord to start both your processes.

Comment: I tried to make a run.sh script and put that in the CMD. the run cript contained:

`#!/bin/bash

rabbitmq-server &
wait
./rabbitmqadmin import /rabbitconf.json
`
This did not work either

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73520/discussion-between-user3594184-and-adrian-mouat).